# xpatchcmd with placeholders

Tags: patching, xpatch

Is there an alternative to `\xpatchcmd` from the `xpatch` package which supports placeholders as in this virtual example:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}{this is important \foo this is not \bar but this is}
\xpatchcmd{\mycommand}{\foo .* \bar}{}{}{}
```

The aim is to achieve the same as

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}{this is important but this is}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible with `xpatch`, but it is with the (experimental) `regexpatch` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{this is important \foo this is not \bar but this is}

\regexpatchcmd{\mycommand}{\c{foo} .* \c{bar}}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\mycommand

\texttt{\meaning\mycommand}

\end{document}
```

Note that control sequences in the search regular expression must be denoted by `\c{<cs-name>}` as in the example.

[image]